# can recursion be leaking memory?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a project that really needs memory management. thing is when I call a recursive function I see in task manager that a memory has been taken and after the recursive function ends the memory doesn't get freed. If you look the only things that effect the memory is the int q that must be given back to the system after the function ends and calling functions must not take any memory.

Note : bin is just a image and a is a 2d array that are global so not much memory usage from them!

```
void inline helpbig(int y , int x)
    {
    int q;
    q = (int) CV_IMAGE_ELEM(bin,uchar,y,x);
    if (q==0)
        a[y][x]=-1;
    if (q==255 && a[y][x]!=1 && a[y][x]!=2)
    {
        max1+=1;
        a[y][x] = 1;
        if (y!=0)
        {
            if (a[y-1][x]==0)
                helpbig(y-1,x);
        }
        if (y!=bin->height-1)
        {
            if (a[y+1][x]==0)
                helpbig(y+1,x);
        }
        if (x!=bin->width-1)
        {
            if (a[y][x+1]==0)
                helpbig(y,x+1);
        }
        if (x!=0)
        {
            if (a[y][x-1]==0)
                helpbig(y,x-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note : The recursive function is used to find some dots that are together.

Comment: You should read a bit about recursion and how it uses the stack. Every level of recursion places the local variables there (plus the ovehead incurred by storing the return address and maybe saving registers), so the stack depth is determined by the depth of your recursion at any given time.

Comment: wild guess, but `CV_IMAGE_ELEM` probably dynamically allocates memory and expects you to later free it, your function never does this. So even though the functions has exited, that memory is still allocated, it's been leaked.

Comment: @Leeor Stack size is typically fixed though, hence stack overflows. When dynamically allocated memory is freed, there is no guarantee it will be given back to the OS immediately. And usually, it won't. That doesn't mean you have a leak.

Comment: I could add the code that is calling the function maybe that could help ?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly free any stack.  Like @thecoshman says - what does CV_IMAGE_ELEM do, and what does it return?

Comment: @BoBTFish, I was commenting on the question "is recursion *taking* memory". Perhaps the question should have been "can recursion be *leaking* memory" (he made some edits in between)

Comment: Also, sub-allocators are unknown to the OS - if your process alloctaes a few meg from the OS and manages it itself, the Task Manager will report it as allocated, since from the OS POV, it is.

Comment: I don't think cv_image_elem takes any memory , it only goes and gets a property of a pixel like r from the rgb and puts it in the int

Comment: OK, then I doubt that you are leaking anything, it just looks like you are from the Task Manager.

Comment: Your program snippet doesn't contain any dynamic allocations, so it cannot leak memory.

Comment: unsure, wether to up or downvote this. +1 for the recursion question, -2 for using the c-api (dead since 2010) also, manipulating global vars from a recursive function is outright criminal.

Comment: @berak , I found the solution , but another small question came to me , what is c-api ? and why using it is bad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your program tries to allocate memory, it gets it from its free memory pool.  When this runs low, it will request more memory from the OS.  However, when you release memory within your program, it will return to your program's free memory pool, but it will not (usually) be returned to the OS until the program exits.

Comment: What makes you think that the memory is not available to the program?  There are no memory leaks in the code that you posted, unless there is inside an overloaded operator or in `CV_IMAGE_ELEM()`.

Comment: The Paragraph you wrote almost gave me the solution , The thing is that the first time it went to the recursive function , it got some memory (stack). The memory was unchanged until the recursive function was called again , after that the next calls some time the recursive calling time was more than the last time therefore it needed to get a little more stack (more memory). because of that the bigger stack still remains in the programs memory territory.